# Image are not showing in table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, sdwebimage

i am trying to get a list of items from mysql and display them in the app.
names appear but the image and price dose not.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell", for: indexPath)
    var cell:UITableViewCell? =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell", for: indexPath)
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle,
                               reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
    }

    // Get the location to be shown
    let item: Location = locations[indexPath.row]
    //  let price=locations[indexPath.row].price

    let price=(item.price as NSString).floatValue
    let cellPrice = String(format: "%.2f",price)
    let serverurl=NSURL(string: "https://myoscapp.com/boot/images/")
    let imageaddress = locations[indexPath.row].image
    let imageURL = NSURL.init(string: imageaddress, relativeTo: serverurl! as URL)
    cell?.textLabel?.text=locations[indexPath.row].name
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = cellPrice
    cell?.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: imageURL! as URL )
    cell?.setNeedsLayout() //invalidate current layout
    cell?.layoutIfNeeded() //update immediately
    return cell!

}
```

Comment: I think `imageURL as URL?` should be `imageURL as! URL` as function is expecting a `URL` not an optional `URL`

Comment: does it get changed if you try a hardcoded dummy url?

Comment: 1. Make print your item. Does it contain the price value? 2. For the image print the imageURL and open this URL in your browser, so you will see if url is not valid.

Comment: i have made some changes and i get the image now but still no subtitle yet. i will update the post with new code

Comment: If you have to just display your price simply use : cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(item.price)"    
No need of conversion, simply display the string

Answer (score 0):

i got everything to work like this. i don't know if for:indexPath is going to have an effect but i don't see anything

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell", for: indexPath)
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle,
                               reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
    // Get the location to be shown
    let item: Location = locations[indexPath.row]
    //  let price=locations[indexPath.row].price

    let price=(item.price as NSString).floatValue
    let cellPrice = String(format: "%.2f",price)
    let serverurl=NSURL(string: "https://myoscapp.com/boot/images/")
    let imageaddress = locations[indexPath.row].image
    let imageURL = NSURL.init(string: imageaddress, relativeTo: serverurl! as URL)
    cell.textLabel?.text=locations[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = cellPrice
    cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: imageURL! as URL )
    cell.setNeedsLayout() //invalidate current layout
    cell.layoutIfNeeded() //update immediately
    return cell

}
```